# Old Screen From Activity Gets Displayed When Back Button Used

Tags: android-listview, android-activity, android

I guess I do not understand how things like the "Back Button" affect how Activities behave.

Here is my main activity screen shot:

[image]

If the user clicks the bookmark icon in the upper right, my BookmarksActivity displays like so:

[image]

Here the user clicks the Add button to add the bookmark and I call `finish()` in my BookmarksActivity class and the screen returns to the my MainActivity ...

[image]

Now let's say the user wants to delete a bookmark, they would again click the bookmark icon which presents the user with this screen:

[image]

Now the user can click on the delete button resulting in this screen:

[image]

Now the user wants to get back to the MainActivity's screen by pressing the Back Button, doing so removes the keyboard as one would expect, resulting in this screen:

[image]

But now the user still wants to get back the main screen, so they click the Back Button again, but instead of the main screen one would expect to see they see this one!

[image]

Now there is no bookmark in my SQLite database yet one is being displayed.  If the user clicks that back button again they do, finally, get the main activity screen ...

[image]

... and if they click on the Bookamrk icon you can see that there is no bookmark:

[image]

Thanks for bearing with me and that lengthy description of the problem.  Here is what I believe to be the pertinent snippets of code:

Here's where the delete happens:

```
public class BookMarksBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

    ...

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookmark, null);

    TextView    tv_bookmark_name    = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_name); 
    TextView    tv_bookmark_clock   = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.bookmark_clock);
    Button      deleteButton    = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_bookmark);

    final bookMark bookmark = new bookMark(data.get(position).get_bookmark_name(), data.get(position).get_bookmark_track(), data.get(position).get_bookmark_clock(), 0);
    final String    bookmark_name = bookmark.get_bookmark_name();
    final int       ibookmark_clock = bookmark.get_bookmark_clock();

    // Setting all values in listview
    tv_bookmark_name.setText(bookmark_name);
    tv_bookmark_clock.setText(utils.milliSecondsToTimer(ibookmark_clock));
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d( TAG, "delete button clicked line 73" ); 
            db.deleteBookmark(bookmark);
            v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), com.redcricket.myApp.BookMarksActivity.class));
        }
    });
    return vi;
}
```

And here is the an snippet from my BookmarkActivity `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    currentChapterTitle     = com.redcricket.myApp.MainActivity.getTrackTitle(0);
    currentTrack            = com.redcricket.myApp.MainActivity.getCurrentSongIndex();
    currentTrackPosition    = "00:00:00";

    db = new Databasehandler(this);
    db.getWritableDatabase();

    utils = new Utils();

    try {
        currentChapterTitle = com.redcricket.myApp.MainActivity.getCurrentTrackTitle();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d( TAG, "expection line 27" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        icurrentTrackPosition = com.redcricket.myApp.MainActivity.getCurrentTrackPosition();
        currentTrackPosition = utils.milliSecondsToTimer(icurrentTrackPosition); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d( TAG, "expection line 34" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.bookmarks);

    try {
        new_bookmark_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_bookmark_name);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d( TAG, "expection line 43" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        new_bookmark_name.setText( currentChapterTitle );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d( TAG, "expection line 49" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        new_bookmark_clock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.new_bookmark_clock);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d( TAG, "expection line 55" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        new_bookmark_clock.setText( currentTrackPosition );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d( TAG, "expection line 61" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add_new_bookmark);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d( TAG, "expection line 43" );
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    addButton.setOnClickListener(this);     
    bookMarkList = db.getAllBookmarks();
    // add list
    bookmark_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.bookmarks_list);
    adapter=new BookMarksBaseAdapter(this, bookMarkList, this); 
            bookmark_list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I must be doing something wrong somewhere.  I have tried to override the `onBackButton` method and have it call finish but that didn't help at all.  My best guess is that this line in wrong:

```
            v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), com.redcricket.myApp.BookMarksActivity.class));
```

I call that when the delete button get pressed.

Any help welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming Main is one activity, book mark is another activity and book mark delete is another activity. Unless you tell an activity to have no history or explicitly finish it before going to another activity it will stay in the activity stack.

In your example the user goes MainActivity -> BookMarkActivty then back to MainActivity through on back pressed which removed BookMarkActivity from the stack. Its all good.

In your other example the user goes MainActivity -> BookMarkActivity -> DeleteActivity

the question here is when they click delete are you finishing DeleteActivty or starting a new BookMarkActivty?

It looks like you are starting a new BookMarkActivty, finished the old BookMarkActivity and ended up with a stack of Main - DeleteBookMark - BookMark after the deletion process.

Don't finish bookmark when they choose to do a delete and set the delete activity to have no history or explicitly finish it after delete.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! There is no DeleteActivity (maybe there should be one?) The delete takes place in this class `public class BookMarksBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter` there is this code in the `bookmark_list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.bookmarks_list); adapter=new BookMarksBaseAdapter(this, bookMarkList, this); bookmark_list.setAdapter(adapter);` in the onCreate method of the BookmarksActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Doh! I figured out what I needed to do.  I need to save the `Activity` that gets passed to the constructor of my `BookMarksBaseAdapter` class as a private member like so ...

public class BookMarksBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

```
private Activity  activity;
...

BookMarksBaseAdapter (Activity a, ArrayList<bookMark> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    utils = new Utils();
    db = new Databasehandler(a);
}
```

... then I call call `activity.finish()` when the delete button gets pressed like this ...

```
deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            db.deleteBookmark(bookmark);
            activity.finish();
        }
    });
```